# find the closest shop to a coordinates

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, coordinates

My code now finds all the places in my local area and append the coordinates in an array.

```
func performSearch() {
    matchingItems.removeAll()

    let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = "starbucks"
    request.region = mapView.region

    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)

    search.start(completionHandler: {(response, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print("Error occured in search: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        } else if response!.mapItems.count == 0 {
            print("No matches found")
        } else {
            print("Matches found")

            for item in response!.mapItems {


                self.matchingItems.append(item.placemark.coordinate)
                print("Matching items = \(self.matchingItems)")

                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.coordinate = item.placemark.coordinate
                annotation.title = item.name
                self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

but what I want is to find the closest shop to my client. I have my client's coordinates saved in a variable. 
Thank you

Comment: Closest in what term? Itinerary? Coordinates? For instance, if you have a Starbucks across the highway, it may be closer, but you may take more time to go around the highway rather than moving to the other one on the same side as you.

Comment: Good question. Closest in term of kilometers by driving @Larme

Answer (score 1):

I believe the MkMapItem has a CLPlacemark property called placemark, otherwise you can use this CLGeocoder function to return a CLPlacemark with just the address:

```
func geocodeAddressString(_ addressString: String, 
    completionHandler: @escaping CLGeocodeCompletionHandler)
```

then use .distance function of the CLPlacemark's location (CLLocation) property to compare to the user's current location like this:

```
let distanceInMeters = placemark.location.distance(from: MKUserLocation) // result is in meters
```

then add this to an array to be sorted:

```
var locationsArray:[Double] = []
locationsArray.append(distanceInMeters)
//then sort the array
locationsArray.sort{ $0 < $1 }
```

then use this sorted array for your tableView or collection view...
Hope this helps! Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The situation I have is I have a delivery app where drivers receives data with shops' names and client's coordinates. I want to get the shop name and so a search to find the closest shop ( kilometers )to the clients, not current location of the driver. @Ercell0

Comment: well, then just use your own CLLocation instead of MKUserLocation. :)

Comment: Still don't get how to add all of the locations in an array and find the closest one to client and display it